# MySQL - Как правильно связать таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы - посты и комментарии к ним:

```
**oc_blog**
| blog_id | date_added | count_read |
| 1       | 04.04.18   | 10         |
| 2       | 05.04.18   | 2          |
| 3       | 06.04.18   | 5          |
| 4       | 07.04.18   | 1          |

**oc_blog_comment**
| blog_id | date_added | comment |
| 1       | 05.04.18   | blabla  |
| 3       | 05.04.18   | blabla  |
```

Связываю их таким запросом

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " .
  DB_PREFIX . "blog i
  LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_description id ON (i.blog_id = id.blog_id)
  LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_to_store i2s ON (i.blog_id = i2s.blog_id)
  LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_comment ic ON (i.blog_id = ic.blog_id)
WHERE
  id.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND
  i2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND
  i.status = '1' AND
  i.sort_order <> '-1'";
```

Выборку потом делаю `$sql .= " ORDER BY comment DESC, i.blog_id LIMIT " . (int)$start . "," . (int)$limit;`

Но при этом, выдаются даты постов 01.01.1970.
Как я понимаю, это в результате того, что постам из первой таблицы присваиваются даты размещения комментариев - из второй таблицы, а недостающие забиваются нулями.

Вопрос - как правильно их связать, чтоб даты комментариев не замещали даты постов?

Это модуль Opencart`a. Данный файл - модель, он делает запрос в базу (запрос написал выше) и затем передает контролеру:

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
return $query->rows;
```

Контролер потом разбирает этот ответ. В частности, дата берется так:

```
'date_added_full' => date(
  $this->language->get('date_format_short'),
  strtotime($result['date_added'])
)
```

Comment: Покажите весь запрос

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM
             " . DB_PREFIX . "blog i LEFT JOIN 
             " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_description id ON (i.blog_id = id.blog_id) LEFT JOIN 
             " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_to_store i2s ON (i.blog_id = i2s.blog_id) LEFT JOIN 
             " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_comment ic ON (i.blog_id = ic.blog_id) WHERE id.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' 
             AND i2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND i.status = '1' AND i.sort_order <> '-1'";

Comment: А теперь покажите как Вы получаете дату поста?

Comment: Извините, я лишь только вникаю. Это модуль Opencart`a.
Данный файл - модель, он делает запрос в базу (запрос написал выше) и затем передает контролеру:
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->rows;
Контролер потом разбирает этот ответ. В частности, дата берется так:
'date_added_full' => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($result['date_added'])),

Comment: Т.е., если сформировать главный запрос без строки LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_comment ic ON (i.blog_id = ic.blog_id), то дата выводится нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у Вас в двух таблицах есть поле с именем `date_added` и обращаясь к полю как `$result['date_added']` Вы обращаетесь к полю другой таблицы.

Решение проблемы, в выборке дать полям различные имена

```
$sql = "SELECT
  i.`date_added` AS `post_date`,
  ic.`date_added` AS `comment_date`
FROM " .
  DB_PREFIX . "blog i
  LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_description id ON (i.blog_id = id.blog_id)
  LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_to_store i2s ON (i.blog_id = i2s.blog_id)
  LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_comment ic ON (i.blog_id = ic.blog_id)
WHERE
  id.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND
  i2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND
  i.status = '1' AND
  i.sort_order <> '-1'";

'date_added_full' => date(
  $this->language->get('date_format_short'),
  strtotime($result['post_added'])
)
```

Или, если второе поле не нужно, не выбирать его.

А самое главное - **НИКОГДА** не использовать конструкцию `SELECT * FROM`! **Всегда** указывать список конкретных полей, которые нужно выбрать, даже если этих полей десятки. На одни грабли, связанные с этой конструкцией, Вы уже наступили. Поверьте, есть еще и не одни